# Alpaca framework select with multiple:true inherits the selection status of its former siblings

Tags: javascript, web, alpacajs

This issue original raise on github of alpaca framework, `https://github.com/gitana/alpaca/issues/731` 
Just open one here for getting support from stackoverflow community.

```
A Combination of multi select and array cause a problem that the second and later select boxes inherit the selection status of their former siblings.
See my codepen: https://codepen.io/hadakadenkyu/full/pooKyzy
```

any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue was related to the object `datasource` that you've created.
Internally alpacajs transforms your `datasource` object to text and value, and it needs it to be only of type `{key: value}` so in your example you should do `{"2001": 2002}` for example.

Moreover, in your alpaca form data object you should use select option values not text like:  `year: ["2001", "2003"]`

**Update:**
I rechecked the documentation and I saw:

> Datasource for generating list of options. This can be a string or a function. If a string, it is considered S be a URI to a service that produces a object containing key/value pairs or an array of elements of structure {'text': '', 'value': ''}. This can also be a function that is called to produce the same list.

So to make your example works you should wrap your `datasource` object value into a function like:

```
dataSource: function(callback) {
                callback([
                  { "text": "2000", "value": 2000 }, ...
```

Here's the first [example](https://codepen.io/vert3x/pen/gOgQdvo).

Here's the second [example](https://codepen.io/vert3x/pen/ZELmqRL).